# Deploy Sitecore Jss React App to Azure Content Delivery

Tags: jss

I tried to deploy my JSS React App to Azure scaled CD. I got my Jss App deployed to Azure CM successfully and it's working as expected.

**Steps to deploy to Azure CD**

1. The Azure scaled CD was setup by using the Azure ARM template from github (https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates/tree/master/Sitecore%209.0.2/XP)
2. Copy the files in the  Sitecore JavaScript Services Tech Preview
   Server 9.0.1 rev. 180724.zip to the wwwroot folder
3. Copy the JssReactWeb.config and JssReactWeb.deploysecret.config
   manually to CD . The hostname in JssReactWeb.config is the CD url
   eg. mysite-sitecore-scaled-test-cd.azurewebsites.net and the
   deployment secret is same as CM
4. I ran "jss deploy files" and the "wwwroot/dist/JssReactWeb" folder deployed
   successfully
5. Approved and publish all the JSS items to web database

When I browse to the home page, I get the following error:

> [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address]
>   System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data) +113
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExport(NodeInvocationInfo
>   invocationInfo) +155
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.InvokeExport(String
>   moduleName, String exportNameOrNull, Object[] args) +217
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry(String
>   moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean
>   allowRetry) +139
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry(String
>   moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean
>   allowRetry) +437
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExport(String
>   moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args) +91
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke(String
>   moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs) +144
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter
>   writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String
>   functionName, Object[] functionArgs) +73
>   Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter
>   writer) +240
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer
>   renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args) +147
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs
>   args) +74    (Object , Object ) +14
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
>   +236    Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String
>   pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
>   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) +331
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   +375    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +88
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +775
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +775
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +81
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39

Has anyone experience this error before?

Answer (score 3):

The issue was the  Node version is not set on the CD app service. If the node version is not set, it will default to node 0.11.

To set the node version, go to Azure portal -> your app service -> Application Settings, add a new app setting 
Name: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 
Value: node version

Comment: You can also find more information on deploying JSS apps to Azure on the JSS docs site: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/techniques/azure-deployment