# Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address

Tags: jss

I am using Sitecore 9.1. I can able to run my sample angular application in connected mode using the command ">jss start:connected".

But i cant able to open my site in local integrated mode , even in experience editor mode. Its throwing below error

Below image is in normal mode.

[image]

Below image is in experience mode.

[image]

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: address**
    at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(String address, String data)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance.InvokeExport[T](NodeInvocationInfo invocationInfo)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportNameOrNull, Object[] args)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
    at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

My scconfig.json below

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\sc910.sc",
    "apiKey": "{A3175524-032C-40F2-88EA-E3C9D57B8D40}",
    "deploySecret": "6g9003yzzjr14fgu0lojm8ccj6ztqsnodpyr6yrlgjttr",
    "deployUrl": "http://sc910.sc/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "layoutServiceHost": "http://my-angular.dev.local"
  }
}
```

I checked node path environment variable als. Everything fine. How to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Related question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15086/deploy-sitecore-jss-react-app-to-azure-content-delivery

Check your node version to ensure it is 10.x (recommended). Though you may also be able to use 8.11 or greater. The error you're seeing basically indicates that the node.exe instance is not running and that the Sitecore->node rendering engine is not able to communicate with it.

Comment: @AdamWeber My older node version is 8.6 , now i installed  V10.15.1 its up and running. I cant find node js compatability here https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164. Do u have compatability table node with sitecore , please post as answer. I will accept urs.

Comment: We always recommend the latest LTS version of Node, which at this point is 10.15: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install#nodejs
We could probably state this more clearly in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by checking your node version to ensure it is the latest LTS version (currently 10.15.1), which is what we generally recommend: https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install#nodejs

The error you're seeing basically indicates that the node.exe instance is not running and that the Sitecore-to-Node rendering engine is not able to communicate with the Node instance.

Note: you *may* be able to use Node 8.11 or greater, but we'd still recommend latest LTS. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Our version of Node.js was not running because they removed the version from Azure :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore 10.3 (initial release) Headless - NextJS

I got a very similar error:
`Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer:Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

My issue was caused by improperly set security rules on the role or user level. In the Sitecore Security Editor, if a user has been explicitly denied read access to `sitecore/Layout`, `sitecore/System` and their respective descendants, these users will get this error on load of Experience Editor.

Hope this helps someone save some time.